# Individually displaying stored items in an array

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I've been having issues displaying items that i saved from my database in an array. My table has two columns for 'name' and 'details'. I successfully retrieved them using mySQLi and stored in an array but instead of displaying all the columns at once, I want to place them at different places on my webpage. eg 
`<p>$Name1: $Details1</p>`. then on another section of the same page 
`<p>$Name2: $Details2</p>`. This is my code:

```
<?php
include ("config/database.php");
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $passwd, $database);
if ($mysqli-> connect_errno){
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n",$mysqli-> connect_error);
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT name, details FROM recent_properties LIMIT 3";

if($result = $mysqli->query($query)){

printf("%s: %s<br>", $row["name"], $row["details"]);
    $result->free();
}
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: What is the problem? Please provide any errors that you may have... What have you tried so far?

Comment: If you're trying to display multiple elements from an array use a loop

Answer (score 0):

Did you try like this.Make use of `loop`. To display all the records.

```
$query = "SELECT name, details FROM recent_properties LIMIT 3";

$result = $mysqli->query($query);

if($result->num_rows()>0)
{
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
    printf("%s: %s<br>", $row["name"], $row["details"]);
    }
}

$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: yes Hek mat, my loops through the row and displays all the records. But I dont want to display all the records at once. I dont know how to pick the items from the array one by one to display. eg. $row["name"][0], $row["details"][0], then $row["name"][1], $row["details"][1] and so on

Comment: This is my recent code<?php
include ("config/database.php");
/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT name, details FROM recent_prop";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);

/* free result set */
$result->free();

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through your `$result` and fetch an associative array:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["name"], $row["details"]);
}
```

EDIT:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<p>'.$Name1.': '.$Details1.'</p>';
    // Whatever else in this section
    // You can even break out of PHP and then
    // get back into PHP again if you have a lot of HTML.
}
```

Comment: I want to display items individually

Comment: You can use an `if` statement inside the loop. `if ($row["name"] == "Dahlia") { echo $row["details"]; }` Does this help?

Comment: Honestly, no. Because im not searching the array for a particular value, i just want to display all items of the array. but not in the same place

Comment: Can you be more specific about "not in the same place"? What different places do you want to use? Do you want them in a table? You can embed any kind of HTML inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT name, details FROM recent_properties";

$result = $mysqli->query($query);

if($result->num_rows()>0)
{
    $html = "<table>";
    $html .= '<tr><th>Name</th><th>Details</th></tr>';
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $html .= '<tr>';
        $html .= '<td>' . $row["name"] . '<td>';
        $html .= '<td>' . $row["details"] . '<td>';
        $html .= '</tr>';
    }
    $html .= "</table>";
    echo $html;
}

$mysqli->close();
```

this is the simplest way to create HTML content from data

in your case you can do some thing like this

```
if ($result->num_rows() > 0) {
    $dataArray = [];
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $dataArray[$row["name"]] = $row["details"];
    }
}
```

and then use the array in your HTML

```
<body>
    <p><?php echo 'a: ' . $arrayData['a']  ?></p>
    <p><?php echo 'b: ' . $arrayData['b']  ?></p>
    <p><?php echo 'c: ' . $arrayData['c']  ?></p>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Mahdi, but what did u mean to use 'dataArray' in the HTML instead of 'arrayData'